# increase and decrease value in input with react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a product counter, which can increase and decrease, the current value of the number of products I am showing in an input with "value", the idea is that the user can enter the number of products without using the increase or decrease buttons.

The problem is that when I have a single number between 0-9 and I manually delete that (in the view) it comes out as a NaN value, and automatically the increase and decrease buttons stop working, and the NaN value cannot be deleted either to rewrite a number

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Products: React.FC = () => {
    

    const [products, setProducts] = useState({
        count: 0
    })

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        
        setProducts({count: parseInt(e.target.value)})
    }

    const decrease = (e: any) => {
        if(products.count <= 0){
            return 
        }
        setProducts({count: products.count - 1})
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input type='button' onClick={decrease}/>
            <input type='text' value={products.count} onChange={handleChange}/>
            <input type='button' onClick={() => setProducts({count: products.count + 1})}/>
            
        </div>
        
    )
}

export default Products
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `parseInt` on the empty string gives `NaN`:

```js
console.log(parseInt(''));
```

Then, once `products` gets set to `NaN`, any further numeric operations on `NaN` will also result in `NaN`.

Alternate the numeric input value (with `Number`) with 0, to turn the empty string into 0:

```
setProducts({count: Math.round(Number(e.target.value) || 0}))
```

You can also consider giving the input the attribute `type="number"` (just for semantic purposes and better UI for the user - it won't affect the JS).

Comment: Your answer worked for me, but if the user types a "-" "NaN" keeps showing up.

Comment: You can use `|| 0` to turn `NaN` into 0 too, see edit

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is to use the correct `input` type, which is `number` in this case.

```js
<input type="number" value={products.count} onChange={handleChange} />
```

then on your `handleChange` you could just do

```js
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setProducts({ count: e.target.value || 0 });
};
```

[image: Edit exciting-rgb-742d9]

Comment: In this way the value 0 can never be removed from the beginning.

Comment: It seems that my solution and the accepted answer does the same thing.

Comment: in the case of using (setProducts ({count: e.target.value || 0})), when I type a number, that number is not replaced by the leading zero, with the case of (Math.round (Number (e .target.value)), when you enter a number, that number replaces the leading zero.


However, in both cases, when entering a "text" type, Nan's case reappears. I clarify that I cannot change the input type to "number" because that would modify my styles